# Is it possible to find the 3d position of the camera relative to a cube (dimentsions known) based on the edges length?

Tags: computer-vision

I am trying to find the relative position of the camera to a fixed cube using the length of the visible edges (2 if the cube is exactly in the front and 3 if its at an angle)

Im entirely new to this field and this is a small portion that will help me in course correction of an autonomous vehicle.

Comment: Shouldn't at least 4 edges of the cube be visible? For the rest this feels like a basic trigonometry question, but probably camera focal length and lens distortion would complicate things a bit.